# Turn on find my mac (and other functions) without admin account

Tags: terminal, command-line, system-settings

I'm managing Macs on my domain, and would like to allow users to turn on find my mac without calling service desk.

I'd need a command line tool for that so I can push it out to all of the users once the script is tested.
I tried to run

```
security authorizationdb write system.preferences allow
security authorizationdb write system.preferences.security allow
security authorizationdb write system.preferences.security.remoterepair allow
```

(and all the system preferences settings)

but not all of them worked. They now can install printers, and set time and date. System Preferences / Security & privacy however didn't open and we DO want that.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running an MDM solution or are these all just set up individually?

Answer (score -3):

Trying to control “adults” can be like herding cats...

Just give them full access and responsibilty for backups / shared drive.

Then if they have an issue all you have to do is wipe and install latest image.

Comment: Not a great idea if they work in a bank:\

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry did not see they worked in a bank, banker... But then never seen macs in any bank, but could happen - not dead yet.

Comment: It doesn't say they work in a bank, but the idea is insecure & relies on users not messing up. Re-imaging would require backup, reload without preserving any other OS/user data. It's just not a great idea.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry, it’s exactly what is supplied to me, full admin access, full responsibility, an IT policy that says if they find inappropriate material I can be terminated instantly and my responsibilty to backup - which I did mention in the answer which you missed, ignored or just did not read. Any issues that take more than 5 min to solve means a re-image and as the data is backed up that works.

Comment: I guess you don't work in a bank then. You are assuming too much in this over-simplistic answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin is a bank the only place to have a job? Seems you missed a large list of other possibilities. No I don’t work in a bank. There are other, perhaps more rewarding, career possibilities.

Comment: You're being rather defensive. I downvoted, I pointed out why I think this is terrible advice. I'm not going to engage further.

Comment: @Tetsujin last time we had a discussion you deleted your own answer:)

Comment: Haha that was a good one. I asked a mac technical question not life guidance or to remodel my work's policy. Thanks anyway laughed good.